# What is the name of a “sub-algebra” without the identity of its super-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-product

We have defined a new finite-dimensional commutative algebra, which is proved semisimple. Let us call it t-algebra. Due to its semisimplicity and commutativity, the t-algebra is a direct product of a finite number of algebraic constituents. These algebraic constituents are all subsets of the t-algebra and are themselves algebras.  However, the multiplicative identity of each constituent is not the same as the identity of the t-algebra. More precisely, the identity of the t-algebra does not belong to any of those mentioned above "sub-algebra". Each of the "subalgebras" has its unique multiplicative identity.

By definition, albeit an algebra itself, each constituent mentioned above is NOT a subalgebra of t-algebra. Then comes my question. What is the name of a “sub-algebra”  without the identity of its super-algebra? Do they have a formal name? Can I coin a name such as quasi-sub-algebra for them?

Comment: What's the term for an algebra of this type without an identity? (Say it's "pre-algebra:" then you're looking at algebras which are sub-pre-algebras but not necessarily sub-algebras, analogously to how we can talk about a sublattice of a Boolean algebra $B$ which is itself a Boolean algebra but is not necessarily a sub-Boolean algebra of $B$.)

Comment: First, thanks. However, I wonder whether the term “pre-algebra” has a source? I have found one from Wikipedia, which sounds not quite formal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-algebra

Comment: I have no idea if it has a prior meaning - I just wanted a term to use as an example.

Comment: Let our t-algebra be $C$, and its two direct constituents be $C_1$ and $C_2$, then $C=C_1×C_2$. All $C$,$C_1$,$C_2$ are algebras. Let the multiplicative identities of $C$, $C_1$, $C_2$ be $E$, $E_1$, $E_2$. We have $E \neq E_1 \neq E_2$, $E \neq E_2 \neq E_1$ but $E_1, E_2 \in C$. What is the name for algebras $C_1$ and $C_2$. The term, by definition, should not be just "subalgebra". If no such a term, I would like to  coin one, say "quasi-sub-algebra".

Answer (score 1):

They’re all ideals and also all quotients. In this particular case I would just call them the “factors.” If you really want to call them subalgebras then maybe “non-unital subalgebras” but I would avoid this personally.

Comment: + for non-unital subalgebras, feels the most technically correct (although probably not the best depending on the context).

Comment: The identity $e$ of one of these constituents $C$ will be an idempotent of the algebra $A$, and then $C=eAe$. This is also called a ‘corner’ in the literature (think of when $A$ is a matrix algebra and $e=E_{11}+\cdots+E_{rr}$).

Comment: Yes, they are all ideals in the context that $C_1$ and $C_2$  are also ring (rng, not subring of $C$). But $C_1$ and $C_2$ are more than rings, they are also vector spaces, which, in my mind, had better be titled by a term containing something algebra-like.  Since $C_1$ and $C_2$ have their own multiplicative identities $E_1$ and $E_2$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ by definition are unital algebra. Thus, I am not sure whether the term "non-unital-subalgebra" is appropriate.

Comment: But in this semi simple case I agree with Qiaochu and would just call them the ‘factors’.

Comment: The term "factor" is technically correct and safe. But the term somehow sounds not enough for me, since "factor" is only appropriate in the universal context that each algebraic constituent is a sub-structure of a direct product. A direct product can be anything such as a ring, a vector space, or an algebra, etc. I would like to have a specific term implying the direct product is an algebra.

Comment: @Liang: how about “factor algebra”?

Comment: @Qiaochu, this term is better for my case  :)

Comment: A thank also goest to Andrew Hubery.